# Grep Subprocess works but Pythons Requests doesn't with the same Parameter

Tags: python, python-requests

When I execute:

```
auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(urllib.parse.quote(self.username), self.token)
response = requests.get(f"https://{url}", verify=True, allow_redirects=True, cert=self.cert, cookies={"test": "test"}, auth=auth)
```

I get an `Authentication required` Error.

But when I run:

```
curl_cmd = [
    "sudo",
    "curl",
    "-X", "GET",
    "--cookie", "test",
    f"https://{urllib.parse.quote(self.username)}:{self.token}@{url}",
    "--cert", f"{self.cert[0]}",
    "--key", f"{self.cert[1]}",
    "-L"
]

process = subprocess.Popen(curl_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

Overthing works perfectly. I am pretty confused. In my username is an '@' so like marcel@mydomain.com does requests do something weird with it? (I already tried it with a session etc.)

(My instance is ubuntu 20.04)

Don't get an `Authentication required` Error.

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` to run `curl`? Even if privileges are needed to read the key, ideally you should have a dedicated service account with no permissions _except_ the ability to read the key and _drop_ down to that. You don't want a bug in OpenSSL or another library curl uses to let someone who takes over the remote server to be able to break into your computer. (So `sudo -u client_key_user curl ...` is what that might look like, if `client_key_user` is the only account that can read the key; of course, you'll want `sudo` configured as restrictively as possible).

Comment: And btw, one thing that _is_ very obvious here is that with curl you're passing a client key (that you presumably don't have permission to even read without using sudo) to the remote server, whereas your `requests` code is only using a specified cert but not replacing the key. Client key authentication is part of how the server ensures that you-the-client are who you claim to be (particularly in high-security environments where username/token isn't considered good enough on its own: the TLS negotiation using the key is done before the username+token combo are even considered).

Comment: Assuming the person who wrote the original version of the code had some semblance of a clue, they wouldn't have used `sudo` unless it was really needed -- which means that it's doing something (like reading the file named by `self.cert[1]`) your Python code doesn't have permission to do _without_ using sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using `urllib.parse.quote` to escape special characters in the username. However, this method doesn't handle the '@' symbol properly in the context of HTTP basic authentication.

Using `subprocess` to execute a curl command from within Python is generally not recommended unless it's necessary for some specific reason. It's better to stick to using Python libraries like `requests` for making HTTP requests.

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
import requests

auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(self.username, self.token)
response = requests.get(f"https://{url}", verify=True, allow_redirects=True, cert=self.cert, cookies={"test": "test"}, auth=auth)
```

By passing the original `self.username` to `HTTPBasicAuth`, you ensure that special characters like '@' are handled properly for HTTP basic authentication within the `requests` library.

Comment: Unfortunatly excatly the same error with your suggestion:

auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(self.username, self.token)
response = requests.get(f"https://{url}", verify=True, allow_redirects=True, cert=self.cert, cookies={"test": "test"}, auth=auth)